# Accessing user files in GAE from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I am new to GAE so struggling to understand a few things.

I am trying to build a python web-app that processes videos uploaded by users (through the webapp) and displays some visualizations (built using d3-js) once the processing is done. The artifacts created during processing are saved locally and later uploaded to user-specific GCS buckets (they are not publically accessible).

I want to be able to display the visualization (using processed video artifacts) when a user requests for it. As per my understanding, since these are dynamically generated, I cannot store the artifacts in static folder for javascript to access. So, it seems that I have to save the processed video artifacts in a `/tmp` folder.

How do I ensure that javascript is able to fetch files from this external `/tmp` folder?
Or is there a better way to do this using GCS itself, how do I access buckets from javascript without making them public?

Please suggest some resources or ideas to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it backwards.

You have a private bucket, that's great for security. In order to have the client javascript (browser, mobile App) to download an object you need to either:

1. Have a HTTP handler for your python GAE that retrieves the file from GCS and sends it to the client. (flask pseudo code)

```py
@app.route('/private/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    ## if user is not authorized 
    #### return 401.
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(name)
    bts = blob.download_as_bytes()
    return bts
```

2. Give the client a [Signed URL from GCS so they can download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#python) the file directly.

```py
@app.route('/private/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    ## if user is not authorized 
    #### return 401.
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(name)
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
        # Allow GET requests using this URL.
        method="GET",
    )
    return url
```

As a note, in the second case the javascript file will need to first access `/prvite/your_file_name` to retrieve the signed url, then it will need to download the actual file from GCS using the signed url.